# Looking for WMS-in-WMS funktionality - a WMS that calls other WMS depending on scale

Tags: geoserver, qgis, forwarding, wms

Sorry to bother you with a probably easy question.

We would like to set up an WMS (web map service) that forwards all the requests to three other WMS depending on the scale (zoom intervall).

The aim is to combine 3 background maps (which show the same geografic area in different levels of detail and come in 3 seperate WMS) into one WMS so the users can zoom in and out seamlessly using just that one WMS that the forwards the WMS-requests to the other 3 WMS.

Is that possible? Is there a software can help me to solve my problem?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

The functionality you are looking for is called cascading. It is possible to do this using [GeoServer](https://geoserver.org).

The [GeoServer manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html) explains in detail how you can set up a cascaded WMS layer. However, there is not currently any way to apply a scale limit to a cascaded layer unless the source server applies it.

Another project that supports cascading WMS is [MapProxy](https://mapproxy.org/) but I'm not sure if it can change sources depending on the scale of the request. It does have the option to limit a request to a [min/max scale](https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.11.0/sources.html#min-res-max-res-or-min-scale-max-scale) but it returns a blank image outside those limits.